# c# The type is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, owin

I'm working on a .net MVC5 project with Microsoft.Owin 4.1. Owin doesn't work the way [I think it supposed to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60264523/no-owin-environment-with-put-requests) so thought that I can get over on this with debugging into the owin source.

The steps were:

Cloned the [aspnetkatana](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana) repo
Added the 3 packages referenced by my project to my solution (right-click on solution > add > existing project)

- Microsoft.Owin
- Microsoft.Owin.Security
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies

Finally added the references to my project (right-click on my project > add > references)

When I try to build the solution it throws errors like:

> The type 'IOwinContext' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

VS marks the line `app.CreatePerOwinContext` as the source of the error.

```cs
    public partial class Startup {

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) {
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(AppUserContext.Create);
            ...
```

Another error complains about the version 4.1.0.0 of the same dependency (which actually is the version I have so this one is quite confusing)

My question is why the owin source not considered by the builder as a v4.1.0.0 assembly and also how to overcome different version needs in a situation like this. I mean I know that if this would happen with NuGet references I could go with `bindingredirect` but don't know how to handle the situation with included source. It also causes some confusion that there wasn't any need to introduce `bindingredirect` when the dependency was included by NuGet. (see below)

**Sidenote:** Before I started to experimenting with including these projects as the source they were added as NuGet packages. No `bindingredirect` was introduced and the build got executed without any errors or warnings. (This part was obviously removed from the csproj file before introduced the owin projects)

The related part in .csproj

```xml
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.4.1.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Security, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.4.1.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.4.1.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

**Edit:**
Also what I'm looking the answer for is how to tell (if possible) the builder that looks for the transient dependencies in the current solution. Clarification: In my solution couple of `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` has been introduced via NuGet. These packages depend on `Microsoft.Owin` and sub-packages. Can I somehow tell to the builder that after these packages have been compiled `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` can use them?

Comment: I have often see this error with targeting different versions of .NET Framework. You are referencing the net45 version of Owin. Is your project targeting something higher such as 4.6?

Comment: @RyanThomas Yep, you put me to the right track with this. After setting all the projects to .net framework 4.5 and after a lot of Update-Packate ... -reinstall if finally compiled! Create an answer please and i'll mark it as accepted answer! Thank you!

Comment: @RyanThomas Ehh sorry, it was a false positive. The build was successful because update-package installed transient dependencies so it reintroduced Microsoft.Owin packages. All the project are set to .net framework 4.5 but still I have the same error message.

Comment: If you go into your web.config does it show the correct version? If not, delete the reference in the config and rebuild. Another way to posibly resolve this is to go to your lib and remove the reference from there.

Comment: I can recommend reading [Binding Redirects](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2020/02/11/binding-redirects/) from [Nick Craver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13249/nick-craver)

Comment: @JamesS Yes, the related part of web.config looks alright to me:
``<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
...``

Get the same build error when remove these lines.  
``App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs(13,13): error CS0012: The type 'IOwinContext' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=3.0 .1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.``